# How to have static page layout

Tags: html, css, layout, browser, web

Below is my code which is the page layout. but if we resize the browser it is keep changing.

how can we have static page layout.

```
<head>
<style> 
body, html { margin:0; padding:0; } 

#wrap { width:100%; height:100%; } 

#header { width:100%; height:15%; text-align:center; border-bottom-style:solid; border-width:thin; background-color:lightyellow; } 

</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="wrap"> 
    <div id="header"> 
    <br><br><br> 
    <label for="tb2">textbox2</label><input type="text" name="tb2" size="30" maxlength="30" id="tb2"> 
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use percentages for your width and height properties, but use absolute values (like `px`, `em`) instead.

`#wrap { width:100px; height:100px; }`

Comment: thanks for the help. but i have some questions. how do we know the complete pixel of width and height of each machine. suppose if i design with pixels and it is working fine with my machine since i am testing in that. how do we know that it will display as same in another machine.

Comment: Test your layout in different browsers and with different resolutions. If you have no means of doing this yourself, then there are plenty of commercial solutions that provide this as a service.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `%` to define height and width's, so use `px`, `em` instead, because if you use `%` than they are relative to your viewport resolution so use `px` instead

```
<style>
div {
   width: 100px;
   margin: auto;
}
</style>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use responsive design to change the style of your site. For example, a 'full sized' display will use a width of 1000px for your main container. A smaller screen size, say for an iPad may set a width of 600px. A mobile device may use 300px. etc...

In your css it would go someting like this...

```
#yourPageContainer{width:1000px;}
#otherElements{background-color:#afa;}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){    
    #yourPageContainer{width:500px;}
    #otherElements{background-color:#aaf;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:300px){
    #yourPageContainer{width:300px;}
    #otherElements{background-color:#faa;}
}
```

The key here is to set absolute widths for your container based on screen size.

I have created an example of this here http://jsfiddle.net/kxRtv/ - try resizing your browser window to see what happens...

This site may provide some inspiration - http://mediaqueri.es/

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered screen resolution problem before and this solved my problem.

- If you want your website to dynamically changing whenever your screen resolution change you can use % in your css to all your page, containers, wrappers etc. so that it will adjust on any screen resolution. (*problem: This destroys your web design whenever the screen resolution is big*)
- The best solution I find so far and I think other professional websites also is doing is to make your width static or fixed(use .px or .em) and just let your page get on the center. This will preserve the design you made on your page and everything will stay and looks as it is. 
  In your CSS just add this line on your page ,containers, wrappers etc. 
   **margin:0 auto;** 
  and your site will be centered to any screen resolution. For more examples and to read more about it check this reference [How to Center a Website With CSS](http://buildinternet.com/2008/11/how-to-center-a-website-with-css/). If you want to test different screen resolutions without changing your actual screen resolution you could try it [here](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/). 
   Hope this helps :)